# How Can I Delete Files with Extended Attributes

Tags: command-line, mac

My system has a bunch of files on an attached WD Mac Passport drive that I think were created by a file synchronization application that I no longer use. I would like to delete these files. All of them list with extended attributes that I cannot delete.

This is what `ls -lo` reports:

```
-rw-r--r--@ 1 Danny Fishing.jpg
```

Here's some of the things I have tried:

- Delete in Finder ... No
- Delete in Terminal; `rm Danny Fishing.jpg` ... Returns "Invalid Argument"

Delete the directory and all files: `rm -r _DelSyncFiles` ...Returns "Invalid Argument" on every file

This is what xattr returns:

```
Danny Fishing.jpg 
com.apple.metadata:_kMDItemUserTags
com.apple.quarantine
```

I have tried to use xattr to remove the extended attributes:

```
xattr -d com.apple.quarantine Danny Fishing.jpg ... "[Errno 22] Invalid argument"

xattr -c com.apple.quarantine Danny Fishing.jpg ... "[Errno 22] Invalid argument"

xattr -cr _DelSyncFiles ... "[Errno 22] Invalid argument" on every file
```

How can I get rid of these 4,000 files?

Comment: From Finder,. Get Info on the drive itself. Depending on format it may have a checkbox to "ignore ownership on this drive". That's the simplest way to take control. If there's no checkbox, let us know what format the drive is. [If it can hold ext atts in the first place, it should be HFS+ or APFS, which ought to let you do that].

Comment: Try the command with quotes around the filenames : `xattr -d com.apple.quarantine "Danny Fishing.jpg"`